# Django forms: Defining model in Meta on the fly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have following form:

```
class EmailPreferences(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Base form used for fields that are always required """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(EmailPreferences, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    class Meta:
        model = teacher_email_preferences
        exclude = ['id', 'c_user']

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        obj = super(EmailPreferences, self).save(commit=commit)
        return obj
```

As you can see model name is fixed which is `teacher_email_preferences`. But my site has two types of user one is `Teacher` other is `Student`. I do not want to create a separate form. So i want to change model to `student_email_preferences` when initiating this form. How can I pass a model here when doing `form = EmailPreferences()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But you can use a closure instead.

```
def emailform(emailmodel):
    class EmailPreferences(forms.ModelForm):
         ...

        class Meta:
            model = emailmodel

         ...

    return EmailPreferences

 ...

form = emailform(teacher_email_preferences)()
```